# Database Table mapping using Model class

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a web application where i have 5 types of user and 5 data base tables for each user type, each table has a column 'username' and 'password'.Also in my login page i have username and password field not user-type field.

i have a model class with the property name username and password. my question is Should i create 5 model class to map 5 tables with same property ? i don't think its a good idea!!.
So how i should create a login class where using only one model class i can map all 5 user table and grant the login.I am using hibernate 3 and Spring MVC 3. Any idea will be appreciated !!! Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have abstract class User that will implement UserDetails interface, from that class you will inherit other classes. On that class use @MappedSuperclass and on others use @Entity

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance. The user_type can be your discriminator column.

If the tables have a similar column structure then you should use [SINGLE TABLE inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_single_table_inheritance_table_in_database). Otherwise use [JOINED table inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_joined_inheritance_annotations).

Comment: Thank you.. will try this approach n let u know..@Vlad